# W3 Total Cache Minification: way to revert back?

Tags: cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

W3 Total Cache Minification: after adding all my js files in the minification settings, what if something screws up? Is is possible to revert back to the original un-minified files?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn off minification. It's not a destructive process, your original files remain untouched.

Comment: OK great. Thanks Milo, jsut needed to know the original files remained untouched.